# How to set a custom url with "admin/" properly for Django Admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-urls

I set **the custom url "admin/success/"** with **"admin/"** as shown below:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("admin/success/", success, name='success'), # Here
]
```

And, this is **"views.py"**:

```py
# "core/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def success(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

Then, I got **"Page not found (404)" error** as shown below:

[image]

But, when I removed **"admin/"**:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

urlpatterns = [
    # path("admin/", admin.site.urls), # Here
    path("admin/success/", success, name='success'),
]
```

**The custom url** is displayed properly as shown below:

[image]

So, are there any ways to properly set **the custom url "admin/success/"** with **"admin/"** so that **the custom url** is displayed properly?

Comment: put the admin/success before the plain admin/

Comment: It is working for me in either way, can you mention the django version you are using?

Comment: I use Django==3.1.7. Yes, @thebjorn's way works properly. It's better if there are more cool ways.

Answer (score 1):

In your `urls.py` just change the arrangement of `/admin` and `/admin/succes`. Because the arrangement matter the last url must be the default one.

For example if in your `app` you have several endpoints, you have to place the default empty endpoint the last one as Django checks all until reaches the default, If you place the empty one first it won't see the others.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/success/", success, name='success'), # Here
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```